# Reading 2 integers that are multiples or not

Tags: c, integer

So I am trying to teach myself C and I picked up a textbook that was recommended to me by a few of my professors and I am working the examples however they don't have answers and I am running into an issue.

QUESTION:
(Multiples) Write a program that reads in two integers and determines and prints if the first
is a multiple of the second. [Hint: Use the remainder operator.]

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2;

    printf("Enter two integers: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);

    if((num2 % num1) == 0);
    {
        printf("%d and %d are multiples of each other\n",num1, num2);
    }

    if((num1 % num2) != 0);
    {
        printf("%d and %d are not multiples of each other\n",num1, num2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

when I run the program I test it with 2 and 5 which are not multiples of each other, however the program prints both statements. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or what it is that I am missing? This chapter of the book only includes if statements and no other types. Thank you!

Comment: i think you meant to test if(num2%num1 !=0) which is the else of the first if right? & not num1%num2

Comment: Think about the *order* of the two numbers in the conditions. And you don't need the second condition really, just an `else`.

Comment: `if(...);` Semicolon, the most classic of newbie bugs :) Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: Warning the question is _determines and prints if the first is a multiple of the second_ **not** _multiples of each other_ (look at my answer)

Answer (score 2):

1. There are stray `;` at the end of each `if`, so the bits in the `{` and `}` are  *always* run. Didn't your compiler warn you of an "empty if"? If not, turn up the warnings.
2. Your `if` conditionals are not mutually exclusive. Use an `if` `else` instead.

Comment: There are no warning produced by gcc even in `-pedantic -Wall` because `if(...);` is valid :-(

Comment: @bruno: `-Wextra` will warn you of this.

Comment: oh, this is ... extra ^^

Comment: @bruno Use `-Wextra`.  Maybe you think `-Wall` meant all warnings? Not so. It means "a fistful of warnings." And `-Wextra` means "a few warnings more".

Comment: @bruno: Rule of thumb: use `-Wall` in your build system, but build with `-Wextra` and `-Wconversion` from time to time.

Comment: @bruno: The fact that code is valid C does not mean a compiler should not warn about it. The goal of programming is not merely to translate source code into an executable. A goal of programming is to make computers do what we want. Therefore, a compiler ought to warn about things in source code that are probably not doing what the programmer intended, even if they are valid C. That is a tricky thing, but a construct like `if (foo);` is more often a mistake than an intentional statement, so the compiler should warn.

Answer (score 1):

> QUESTION: (Multiples) Write a program that reads in two integers and determines and prints if the first is a multiple of the second.

**warning** : your first test `if((num2 % num1) == 0)` is not compatible with that, you probably wanted (if I forget the extra ';') `if((num1 % num2) == 0)`

The goal is not to know if they are multiples of each other (and this is not what your program does anyway)

As bathsheba says the extra ';' closed your *if*

I also encourage you to check the result of *scanf*

You can also reduce your code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2;

    printf("Enter two integers: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2) == 2) {
      printf("%d is %smultiple of %d\n",
             num1, ((num1 % num2) == 0) ? "" : "not ", num2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
 /tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra c.c
 /tmp % ./a.out
Enter two integers: 6 2
6 is multiple of 2
 /tmp % ./a.out
Enter two integers: 5 3
5 is not multiple of 3
```

Comment: Upped for scanf check.